# Material UI | React | OnClick Event always sends the last index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, list, listview

I am unable to select the listItem properly

I am a beginner to React and i am having trouble in iterating through List Item in Material UI . I am iterating through a json array and adding list item to a list. ***On clicking any list item , the list always selects the last item***

```
 function handleListItemClick(index) {
    setSelectedIndex(index);

    props.user.updateState(index);
    props.user.setCourseName(props.mycourses[index].courseName);
  }

  function RenderListItem(props) {
    var indents = [];
    let ind = 0;

    for (var key in props.coursevals) {
      indents.push(
        // <span>

        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === key}
          onClick={() => handleListItemClick(key)}
          // onClick={event => handleListItemClick(event, 0)}
          className={classes.ListItem}
          key={key}
        >
          {/* {console.log(key)} */}
          <ListItemIcon>
            <img
              className={classes.courseimg}
              src="../../../public/images/book.png"
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={props.coursevals[key].courseId} />
          <img
            className={classes.rightarrow}
            src="../../../public/images/rightarrow.png"
          />
        </ListItem>
      );
    }
    return indents;



 }
```

***OnClick Event always send the last index to the function. I want to send the index where i just clicked***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the variable `key` is the same for each iteration (it will be updated with the new key on each loop start). You're passing a callback which has a reference to that variable that at the end of the iteration will have the value of the last key.

I wasn't able to test the following code but it should work. Please let me know. The idea is to keep a reference to the "current key" for each loop, so each callback will reference to the correct value.

Note that I've replaced all `key` appearances inside the `for` body just to be more consistent. Expressions that are evaluated in real time (not at callback time) obviously doesn't have this problem.

Another, more fancy way would be to use `Function.prototype.bind()` (See on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)). `onClick={handleListItemClick.bind(undefined, key)}`. It will pass a function with `key` embedded as the first argument.

Last alternative, using `forEach()` instead of a for loop would work because a new `index` will be created for each iteration. (Same result as with the code below).

```
 function handleListItemClick(index) {
    setSelectedIndex(index);

    props.user.updateState(index);
    props.user.setCourseName(props.mycourses[index].courseName);
  }

  function RenderListItem(props) {
    var indents = [];
    let ind = 0;

    for (var key in props.coursevals) {
      let currentKey = key;
      indents.push(
        // <span>

        <ListItem
          button
          selected={selectedIndex === currentKey}
          onClick={() => handleListItemClick(currentKey)}
          className={classes.ListItem}
          key={currentKey}
        >
          {/* {console.log(currentKey)} */}
          <ListItemIcon>
            <img
              className={classes.courseimg}
              src="../../../public/images/book.png"
            />
          </ListItemIcon>
          <ListItemText primary={props.coursevals[currentKey].courseId} />
          <img
            className={classes.rightarrow}
            src="../../../public/images/rightarrow.png"
          />
        </ListItem>
      );
    }
    return indents;



 }
```

Comment: @MuhammadZulqarnainSabir great! See my las edit for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to pass the event as the first parameter

```
onClick={(event) => handleListItemClick(event, key)}
```

And your `handleListItemClick` function should be declared as

```
function handleListItemClick(event, index) {
    event.preventDefault()
    ...
}
```

Comment: still getting the same results, i have two items in the array and on clicking item 0 , the functions prints index 1 on console

Comment: I would use the array.map function because it seems something is amiss with your key 

for (var key in props.coursevals) {

becomes
```
props.coursevals.map((value, index) => {
   ... your code here ...
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please use map instead of for loop. So your code should be look like below.

```
props.coursevals.map((courseval, index) => {
  indents.push(
    <ListItem
      key={index}
      button
      selected={selectedIndex === index}
      onClick={() => handleListItemClick(index)}
      className={classes.ListItem}
    >
      <ListItemIcon>
        <img
          className={classes.courseimg}
          src="../../../public/images/book.png"
        />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={courseval.courseId} />
      <img
        className={classes.rightarrow}
        src="../../../public/images/rightarrow.png"
      />
    </ListItem>
  );
});
```

Hope this will help you!

Comment: Can you please mark an answer as accepted and vote up for this answer? So this will helpful to other developers as well.

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with React but Javascript itself. Beware when using `var` in `for` loops with callback functions. All these functions point to the same value, which is the last index at the end of iteration. Try using `let` instead of `var` or even better: don't use `for` loop at all:

```
const indents = Object.keys(props.coursevals).map(key => (
  <ListItem
      key={index}
      button
      selected={selectedIndex === index}
      onClick={() => handleListItemClick(index)}
      className={classes.ListItem}
    >
    ...
```

You can refer to this question: [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)